# How to output octal values in ColdFusion

Tags: string, coldfusion, ascii, output, octal

I have a series of octal values I'd like to output in their ASCII character equivalents. CHR does not seem to recognize an octal character when it sees it. Is there any straightforward way of doing this with ColdFusion?

Comment: SO uses tags rather than channels and you've tagged your question well, so don't worry on that score

Comment: To add to what barny correctly said, there are also sites for different topic areas - SO is for programming-related questions, but if you jump to the end of the page, you'll see a bunch of sites where non-programming/specialisted questions can be asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**InputBaseN**](http://cfdocs.org/InputBaseN) to convert from Octal to Decimal, then you can use [Chr](http://cfdocs.org/Chr) to output the character.

For example:

```
Chr(InputBaseN( 101 , 8 ))    => A
```

To go back the other way, you can reverse the process with [Asc](http://cfdocs.org/Asc) and [FormatBaseN](http://cfdocs.org/FormatBaseN):

```
FormatBaseN( Asc('A') , 8 )   => 101
```